# Is there an online resource like Jewish Encyclopedia available that is more up to date?

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books, internet

I find the [Jewish Encyclopedia (1901-1906)](http://jewishencyclopedia.com) to be an invaluable resource but alas it is quite old. Is there a similar but more updated encyclopedia available online anywhere?

Comment: Old is not necessarily bad.

Comment: @ezra  I hope I didn't suggest that it was.

Comment: Well I suppose there would be benefits to an updated publication. The Jewish Encyclopedia mentions nothing about the State of Israel and how that impacted Jewish history because it was the very early 1900s.

Comment: @ezra -- Nor does it mention the Holocaust/Shoah.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [Encyclopedia Judaica](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encyclopaedia_Judaica), first published in 1971-1972, and updated as recently as 2007, is a bit more recent than *Jewish Encyclopedia*. While it isn't available online, many of its articles are available from [Jewish Virtual Library](http://www.jewishvirtuallibrary.org/) (most of these articles have "Source: *Encyclopaedia Judaica*" at the bottom, but some articles from *Encyclopedia Judaica* are uncredited).

Comment: @b a -- For some reason, many articles are those of EJ but are not credited to it. See, for example, 'New Testament' and 'Jesus'--both by Dr. David Flusser of Hebrew University--and 'Daniel, Book of' by H. L. Ginsberg.

Comment: @CliffordDurousseau That's strange. I couldn't figure out why from the website, but I updated the answer with your observation

Answer (score 6):

Also available is *Universal Jewish Encyclopedia*, 10 volumes (1939-1943) by Simon Cohen and Isaac Landman at The Online Books Page  ([onlinebooks.library.upenn.edu/](http://onlinebooks.library.upenn.edu/)).*  After entering title, click 'Include extended shelves' when you get the result.  Only volumes 2, 5, 6, and 10 have been digitized by Hathi Digital Library.  Thus it is only partly comparable in usefulness to *EJ*.

*The New Jewish Encyclopedia* (1962) edited by Dr. David Bridger and Rabbi Samuel Wolk is accessible through Amazon.com's **Look Inside** feature.  Ditto for *The Shengold Jewish Encyclopedia* (Revised 3rd edition; 2003) by Mordechai Schreiber and Leon Klenicki. These both are one-volume works and lack the scholarly bibliographies of the multi-volume *JE*, *UJE*, and *EJ*.

---

**The Encyclopedia of Jewish Knowledge* (1934), a one-volume work edited by Jacob De Haas 'in collaboration with more than one hundred and fifty scholars,' is available at Internet Archive (https://archive.org/stream/encyclopediaofje00unse/encyclopediaofje00unse_djvu.txt).  But *Jewish Quarterly Review* devastatingly critiqued it for its numerous inaccuracies in a three-page review in 1937: https://www.jstor.org/stable/1452466[enter link description here](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1452466).